# DropDownList in wrapper class for two classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My problem started when I wrap three classes
the first class is

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID")]
public class Material 
{
   public string MaterialName { get; set; }
}
```

the second  class is

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID")]
public class ExameState 
{
    public string ExamState { get; set; }
}
```

the third class is

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID")]
public class Exams
{
    public string ExamsName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public int Period  { get; set; }
    public int ExamStateID { get; set; }
    public int MaterialID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionState { get; set; }
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public int ExamMarkState { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

wrapper class is

```
public class Examswrapper
{
    public Material material { get; set; }
    public ExameState examstate { get; set; }
    public Exam exam { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to display dropdownlist for Material with datavalue=MaterialName 
and key=ID in view  build on Examswrapper class 
I am trying this

how to make it 
and thank you for your advice

new error :
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: There is no Id in class Material, missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your view model because the `Material` property should be a collection if you want a drop down list. Also your Material class is missing an ID property. So:

```
public class Material 
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string MaterialName { get; set; }
}

public class ExamsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedMaterialId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Material> Materials { get; set; }

    ... // some other properties
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    // This is the property that will hold the selected value
    x => x.SelectedMaterialId,
    // Build the select list based on the Model.Materials collection
    new SelectList(
        Model.Materials.Select(material => new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = material.ID,
            Text = material.MaterialName
        }),
        "Value", "Text"
    )
) %>
```

Comment: there is an error: No overload for method 'Select' takes 3 arguments

Comment: @Abdalmohaymen, yes indeed, I made a mistake. I have updated my post.

Comment: @Abdalmohaymen, did you initialize the `Materials` collection in your controller action?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.material,
        Model.material.Select(
        x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.MaterialName,
            Value = x.Id
        }
    ))
```